# Swig + Numpy.i with a const int16_t pointer

Tags: python, numpy, swig

I am trying to wrap the following function with SWIG so I can call it from Python. The signature is:

```
    int WebRtcVad_Process(VadInst* handle, int fs, const int16_t* audio_frame,
                  size_t frame_length);
```

I have the following SWIG file:

```
    %module webrtc_vad

    %{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "webrtc/common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h"
    %}

    %{
      /* Include in the generated wrapper file */
      typedef unsigned int size_t;
    %}

    %include "stdint.i"
    %include "numpy.i"

    %init %{
      import_array();
    %}

    typedef unsigned int size_t;

    %apply (const int16_t* IN_ARRAY1, unsigned int DIM1) {(const int16_t* audio_frame, size_t frame_length)};
    %include "webrtc/common_audio/vad/include/webrtc_vad.h"
```

At the end of this, I get the following error: `webrtc_vad.i:22: Warning 453: Can't apply (int16_t const *IN_ARRAY1,unsigned int DIM1). No typemaps are defined.`

If I drop the `unsigned` bit in the signature, then it compiles fine but the function signature is carried as-is (i.e. the function expects an int pointer and all that business).

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, but I've had a similar question and it might be of some help.

I don't know why swig does not recognize `unsigned int` as a size because according to the documentation "every int-like type" should work. Using `int` should be sort of fine though.

My problem was using `<stdint.h>` types for arrays (like your `int16_t`) and I've made it work by editing `numpy.i`:

See also the following: [using stdint with swig and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315791/using-stdint-with-swig-and-numpy-i/34316126#34316126)